# dificultad crear vistas java (netbeans)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Hola estoy creando un sistema de votaciones simples con registro de usuarios y posterior login para poder acceder a votar, el problema que  tengo es que al crear las vistas se me genera una especie de "bug" ya que la vista principal al hacer click en el botón "ingresar"  el desplegable sale detrás de la vista principal (como se aprecia en la fotografía), mi pregunta es que podría tener de malo el código para poder arreglar este error, esta es mi primera entrada en este maravilloso sitio desde ya muchas gracias a cualquiera que lea esto.

Este es el código de la vista principal:

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package vista;

/**
 *
 * @author elnie
 */
public class Programa extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JIFrame_login Flogin = new JIFrame_login();

    public Programa() {
        initComponents(); 
        
        this.add(Flogin);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jbtn_ingresar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jbtn_votar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        jPasswordField1.setText("jPasswordField1");

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Registrar Votante", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 0, 13))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

        jbtn_ingresar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/login.png"))); // NOI18N
        jbtn_ingresar.setText("Ingresar");
        jbtn_ingresar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbtn_ingresarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(255, 255, 255)
                .addComponent(jbtn_ingresar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(264, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jbtn_ingresar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Votar", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 0, 18))); // NOI18N

        jbtn_votar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/votar.png"))); // NOI18N
        jbtn_votar.setText("VOTAR");
        jbtn_votar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbtn_votarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jbtn_votar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 198, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(238, 238, 238))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                .addComponent(jbtn_votar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jMenu.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/signo-de-interrogacion.png"))); // NOI18N
        jMenu.setText("Ayuda");

        jMenuItem2.setText("Como votar");
        jMenu.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuBar.add(jMenu);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(130, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jbtn_votarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jbtn_ingresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    
    this.Flogin.show();
    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Programa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Programa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Programa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Programa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Programa().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbtn_ingresar;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbtn_votar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

y esta es la ventana que esta dando problemas la cual queda detrás de la vista principal:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package vista;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author elnie
 */
public class JIFrame_login extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {


    public JIFrame_login() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txt_usuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Txt_contraseña = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jbtn_ingresar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setClosable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        jLabel1.setText("Usuario:");

        jLabel2.setText("Contraseña:");

        txt_usuario.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txt_usuarioActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Txt_contraseña.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Txt_contraseñaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jbtn_ingresar.setText("Ingresar");
        jbtn_ingresar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbtn_ingresarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(txt_usuario)
                            .addComponent(Txt_contraseña, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 175, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                        .addComponent(jbtn_ingresar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(txt_usuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(Txt_contraseña, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                .addComponent(jbtn_ingresar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txt_usuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void Txt_contraseñaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void jbtn_ingresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    }                                             


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField Txt_contraseña;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbtn_ingresar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txt_usuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: aqui se ve como queda por la parte trasera de la vista principal al hacer click en el botón "ingresa"]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas agregando el JIFrame_login después de initComponents();, solamente agrega la linea this.add(Flogin); antes de initComponents(); y se soluciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Muy bien, primero que nada generalmente los `JInternalFrame` se implementan dentro de un `JDesktopPane` que debe tener el *frame*, lo segundo en lo que hay que detenerse es el orden de los componentes en el `JFrame` (primero se agrega el `JInternalFrame` y después todo lo demás).

En ese orden de ideas una solución para este *Bug* quedaría planteada con los siguientes cambios:

**Clase** `JIFrame_login`:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
setClosable(true);
//setVisible(true);
```

La razón de ser de la constante `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` es que si se cierra la `JInternalFrame` perdemos esa instancia y no podremos manipular mas ese objeto, a no ser que se instancie una y otra vez (*algo no muy flexible algunas veces*).

**Clase** `Programa`:

```
public Programa() {
  /*initComponents();
    this.add(Flogin);*/
  JDesktopPane deskPane=new JDesktopPane();
  deskPane.add(Flogin);
  setContentPane(deskPane);
  initComponents();
  Flogin.setLocation(getWidth()/2-Flogin.getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2-Flogin.getHeight()/2);
}
```

Ahora el constructor de `Programa` crea un `JDesktopPane` y lo ubica en el `JFrame` via `setContentPane` donde estará flotando el `JInternalFrame`, luego de eso agrega los demás componentes de paneles y botones; Por ultimo algo mas misceláneo es centrar la ventana con el `setLocation`.